# Count visits of WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, visitor-statistic

I want to show the total number of visitors on my WordPress site.
So far, I'm using a plugin to count the post visitors.
and I did iframe for one post in the footer of site (non-visible).

```
<iframe id="tvc" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/mvc/"  width="50" height="50"></iframe>
```

and finally I called the number of visitors from it by JavaScript.

```
var embedvc = document.getElementById('tvc');
embedvc.onload = function() {
var iframe = document.getElementById("tvc");
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("post-18371")[0];
document.getElementById("total-visits").innerText = elmnt.innerText;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: you may refer this link for detail explanation of my answer https://gretathemes.com/count-post-views/

Comment: this link is about how to count (post views) not generally site visits !!